# Is it legal to create automations of websites in India?

Tags: software, business, india

Is it legal to create automations of websites in India using Python?

There are Flash Sales on every E-commerce sites nowadays, and ordering manual fails to receive goods as they get out of stock in just a second!

So, can we create automations for them and sell this automations to users?

There are many automaters in India which do that, but is it legal?

Comment: What do you mean by automation?

Comment: @Putvi I think Chandu is interested in creating software to automatically connect to websites and quickly order products on behalf of users when they are discounted in a Flash Sale.

Comment: Oh I get you now. TY

Comment: @bdsl yes yiu are correct

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to check is the terms of services of the website. There are plenty of sites where people use programs to buy things now, but if the site tells you not to do it you shouldn't or they could block you from the site.

Comment: Will there be any legal action if I do this, except banning of the account?

Comment: No, why would there be?

Comment: They could sue for breach of contract to keep you from the site though.

Comment: If you or the user or website is in the USA the computer misuse act could be invoked on the grounds that the automated buying is unauthorised.